# MySQL use one subquery more times

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery

I'm just beginner in SQL, so please don't worry :)

I have table where I store dictionary word translates. The table have columns `id`, `la` (language), `lb` (target language), `wa` (original word), `wb` (translated word) and some more insignificant columns :). I want to show a table overview, where will be a list of all languages with count of words in each language plus row with SUM as a language with total words count (all counts of only distinct words).

I wrote this query:

```sql
SELECT `lng`, COUNT(`word`) AS `count` 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT * 
  FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT `la` AS `lng`, `wa` AS `word` 
     FROM `dict_trans` 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT DISTINCT `lb` AS `lng`, `wb` AS `word` 
     FROM `dict_trans`
  ) AS `tbla`
) AS `tblb` GROUP BY `lng`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sum' AS `lng`, COUNT(`word`) AS `count` 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT * 
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT `la` AS `lng`, `wa` AS `word` 
    FROM `dict_trans` 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT DISTINCT `lb` AS `lng`, `wb` AS `word` 
    FROM `dict_trans`
  ) AS `tblc`
) AS `tbld` ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

But I think it's very silly and performance unfriendly doing one subquery more times.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT `la` AS `lng`, `wa` AS `word` 
  FROM `dict_trans` 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DISTINCT `lb` AS `lng`, `wb` AS `word` 
  FROM `dict_trans`
) AS `tbla`
```

I tried in second part of code to pass reference to the table from first part:

```sql
SELECT `lng`, COUNT(`word`) AS `count` 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT * 
  FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT `la` AS `lng`, `wa` AS `word` 
     FROM `dict_trans` 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT DISTINCT `lb` AS `lng`, `wb` AS `word` 
     FROM `dict_trans`
   ) AS `tbla`
) AS `tblb` GROUP BY `lng`
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sum' AS `lng`, COUNT(`word`) AS `count` 
FROM `tblb` 
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```

But error was thrown (#1146 - Table 'db.tblb' doesn't exist).

It's possible to solve this problem without of creating temporary tables?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Normally yes, but this can be done `with rollup`.

Comment: @Strawberry `id` is standard row identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need all the complexity of your query. `UNION` means `UNION DISTINCT` so there is no need for the 3-level nesting and the extra count can be done with the `WITH ROLLUP` modifier:

```
SELECT lng AS language, 
       COUNT(word) AS WordCount 
FROM
  ( SELECT la AS lng, wa AS word 
    FROM dict_trans 
  UNION                                 -- DISTINCT is the default
    SELECT lb, wb 
    FROM dict_trans
  ) AS t
GROUP BY lng
  WITH ROLLUP ;
```

And if you want sorting, you'll need another nesting:

```
SELECT language, WordCount 
FROM
  ( SELECT COALESCE(lng, 'Total') AS language, 
           COUNT(word) AS WordCount 
    FROM
      ( SELECT la AS lng, wa AS word 
        FROM dict_trans 
      UNION                                 -- DISTINCT is the default
        SELECT lb, wb 
        FROM dict_trans
      ) AS t
    GROUP BY lng
      WITH ROLLUP 
  ) AS tmp
ORDER BY CASE WHEN language = 'Total' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         WordCount DESC ;
```

The most expensive part of this query will be the `UNION` (because you need `DISTINCT`) and the `GROUP BY` operations. If you want efficiency, it would be much better to have a separate table with all distinct language and word combinations and then group by on that table (no union would be needed). And the `dict_trans` would be a "junction" table and you'd have 2 foreign keys, pointing to that new distinct languages-words table.

Comment: But statements `ROLLUP` and `ORDER BY` are mutually exclusive, so I must use your code nested to another `SELECT`, where will be used `ORDER BY`